# Dynamic adjustment of Transaction Isolation Level for duration of query

Tags: sql-server

In the midst of **migrating** an enterprise database from **DB2** running on **z/OS** to **sql-server** running on **x86**.  An approach used in one of the **legacy applications relies on DB2s ability to dynamically change the Transaction Isolation Level to READ-UNCOMMITED (only for the duration of the query)**.

We have yet to figure out a way to do the same in sql-server.  I'm aware of the 'WITH (NOLOCK)' and  more persistent SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL approaches.  Hoping to be able to migrate the legacy application without requiring a major effort.

The issue with setting the transaction isolation level is that JPA uses a shared pool filled with database connections pre-initialized to run using READ-COMMMITED.  We'd need to be 100% certain to unset the connection when done with it.

Additional details: legacy app is written in Java and use OpenJPA to automagically create (and run) the SQL queries.  This approach allows us to dynamically adjust the Isolation Level of the query being executed for the duration of the query.

`query.setHint("openjpa.FetchPlan.Isolation", "READ_UNCOMMITTED");`

This eventually comes down to an entry in the OpenJPA DBDictionary for sqlserver. The catch is you can only implement the entry if the underlying database supports the approach.  With sqlserver I get the following error (**openjpa** "**This DBDictionary does not support customization of isolation levels on a per-query basis**").  I am hopeful someone more familiar with sql-server can tell me if I'm missing something.  Thanks in advance.

Is anyone aware of an approach to dynamically adjusting the Transaction Isolation Level only for the duration of the query?

***One potential path from @trenton-ftw is to SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL every time.***  The challenge with that approach is the connection pool contains pre-intialized database connections.  So far not seeing a way to have OpenJPA run the "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL" prior to returning the connection.  I'll update this statement if I can find a way.

Comment: You would have to give more info on what you are describing as 'dynamically adjusting the Transaction Isolation Level only for the duration of the query'? You can use the `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` approach to adjust the transaction isolation level for only the duration of a certain query. So what does that not give you that you need?

Comment: When you say *dynamically change transaction isolation level* it's not clear what you mean - dynamic in what way? You can't change it *during* the execution of a query; you can *set* it before executing a query and *set* it again immediately following execution - what is your actual problem?

Comment: The legacy application is built using Java and its JPA approach to access the entities.  The shared database connections used by JPA are configured to run using the default isolation level READ COMMITTED.  JPA takes care of controlling when the actual commit occurs so we don't programmatically start/commit/rollback the transactions.  In DB2 we give the query a "hint" (call a DB2 api method) which tells it to run using "READ UNCOMMITED" isolation level.  When the query completes, the connection reverts back "READ COMMITED".  Is that any clearer?  LMK

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to do some more reading on the [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql) documentation. A database has a default transaction (tx) isolation level, and when a connection is established a session is created with the database's default tx isolation level. From there, you can edit the connection's tx isolation level using that SET option. A transaction (or query as you describing) uses the tx isolation level currently in use for the session.

Comment: So if you need to edit the tx isolation level for an individual query, you can use the SET option to update the sessions tx isolation level to the desired level and then any query executed in that session will use that tx isolation level. A subsequent query executed in the same session can run in a different tx isolation level as long as you use the SET option to update it to the different tx isolation level.

Comment: If you already understand this, then please describe why this does not work for your use case.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It also appears that Microsoft has some information specifically regarding JDBC drivers and transaction isolation levels in their Microsoft docs on JDBC [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels). I would give that a look and see if you have the ability in OpenJPA to set it in similar fashion to the manner described by Micorosft in that link. If you would like more info on the SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL approach, I can write in to an answer?

Comment: We are reaching the conclusion that we'll probably want to move away from OpenJPA and migrate to Hibernate instead (more consistent with other projects).  We'll migrate the services as needed and implement a REST API instead of the current SOAP.   Since the batch jobs are also moving, we'll need to revisit the batch job locking and avoid the use of the dirty reads except where practically mandatory.  Thanks for your insight.